# golang takes a screenshot of a window using a window handle

Tags: winapi

When I was in golang and called w32 to take a screenshot of the window through the window handle, I found that the results were only black and white, and I didn't know what to do to get the right screenshot

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func TakeScreenshot(hWnd w32.HWND, fileName string) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("HWND: %d", hWnd))
    rect := w32.GetWindowRect(hWnd)
    width := rect.Right - rect.Left
    height := rect.Bottom - rect.Top
    fmt.Println(width, height)

    hdc := w32.GetWindowDC(hWnd)
    defer w32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc)

    dcDest := w32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)
    defer w32.DeleteDC(dcDest)

    hBitmap := w32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcDest, int(width), int(height))
    defer w32.DeleteObject(w32.HGDIOBJ(hBitmap))

    bitmapInfo := w32.BITMAPINFO{
        BmiHeader: w32.BITMAPINFOHEADER{
            BiSize:        uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(w32.BITMAPINFOHEADER{})),
            BiPlanes:      1,
            BiBitCount:    32,
            BiWidth:       width,
            BiHeight:      -height,
            BiCompression: w32.BI_RGB,
            BiSizeImage:   uint32(width * height * 4),
        },
    }
    hOld := w32.SelectObject(dcDest, w32.HGDIOBJ(hBitmap))
    w32.BitBlt(dcDest, 0, 0, int(width), int(height), hdc, 0, 0, w32.SRCCOPY)
    w32.SelectObject(dcDest, hOld)

    pixels := make([]byte, width*height*4)
    w32.GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, uint(height), unsafe.Pointer(&pixels[0]), &bitmapInfo, w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS)

    img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, int(width), int(height)))
    for y := 0; y < int(height); y++ {
        for x := 0; x < int(width); x++ {
            offset := (y*int(width) + x) * 4
            r := pixels[offset+2]
            g := pixels[offset+1]
            b := pixels[offset]
            img.SetRGBA(x, y, color.RGBA{R: r, G: g, B: b, A: 255})
        }
    }
    file, err := os.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func(file *os.File) {
        err := file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }(file)

    if err = png.Encode(file, img); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ERROR SAVING IMAGE: ", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    hWnd := w32.FindWindow("WTWindow", "")
    if hWnd == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Window find err")
        return
    }
    TakeScreenshot(hWnd, "./screenshot.png")
}
```

This is the screenshot I got after executing the function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruAIZ.jpg)

It looks like something's wrong here, But if I change it, it will only make things worse

```
    for y := 0; y < int(height); y++ {
        for x := 0; x < int(width); x++ {
            offset := (y*int(width) + x) * 4
            r := pixels[offset+2]
            g := pixels[offset+1]
            b := pixels[offset]
            img.SetRGBA(x, y, color.RGBA{R: r, G: g, B: b, A: 255})
        }
    }
```

I need any help from these people, thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image#code-example) example?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thank you very much for your reply, I checked [capturing-an-image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image#code-example) example, my problem was solved.

Comment: Could you please answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it out [capturing-an-image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image#code-example) I found that the `HDC` in `CreateCompatibleBitmap` was wrong. I should have used `GetDC` to get the `HDC`. Here is my changed code

```golang
func WindowScreenshot(hWnd w32.HWND, fileName string) {
    zap.S().Info(fmt.Sprintf("HWND: %d", hWnd))
    rect := w32.GetWindowRect(hWnd)
    width := rect.Right - rect.Left
    height := rect.Bottom - rect.Top
    zap.S().Info(width, height)

    hdc := w32.GetDC(hWnd)
    defer w32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc)

    dcDest := w32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)
    defer w32.DeleteDC(dcDest)

    hBitmap := w32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, int(width), int(height))
    defer w32.DeleteObject(w32.HGDIOBJ(hBitmap))
    hOld := w32.SelectObject(dcDest, w32.HGDIOBJ(hBitmap))
    w32.BitBlt(dcDest, 0, 0, int(width), int(height), hdc, 0, 0, w32.SRCCOPY)
    w32.SelectObject(dcDest, hOld)

    bitmapInfo := w32.BITMAPINFO{
        BmiHeader: w32.BITMAPINFOHEADER{
            BiSize:        uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(w32.BITMAPINFOHEADER{})),
            BiPlanes:      1,
            BiBitCount:    32,
            BiWidth:       width,
            BiHeight:      -height,
            BiCompression: w32.BI_RGB,
            BiSizeImage:   uint32(width * height * 4),
        },
    }

    pixels := make([]byte, width*height*4)
    w32.GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, uint(height), unsafe.Pointer(&pixels[0]), &bitmapInfo, w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS)

    img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, int(width), int(height)))
    for y := 0; y < int(height); y++ {
        for x := 0; x < int(width); x++ {
            offset := (y*int(width) + x) * 4
            img.SetRGBA(x, y, color.RGBA{R: pixels[offset+2], G: pixels[offset+1], B: pixels[offset], A: 255})
        }
    }
    SaveImg(img, fileName)
}
```